# Integrate $\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I go about integrating the following:

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}} dx$$

I've tried numerous substitutions but I can't find the right one.

Comment: Up to the substitution $x=1-u^2$, your problem is equivalent to the computation of the area of a circle segment.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $$t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $x=\sin^2\theta$. The integral simplifies to

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{1-\sin^2\theta}}(2\sin\theta\cos\theta) d\theta = \int 2\sin^2\theta d\theta$$

This substitution only works if $0\leq a < b \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=\sin^2t$ so the integral becomes$$\int_{\arcsin\sqrt{a}}^{\arcsin\sqrt{b}}2\sin^2tdt=\int_{\arcsin\sqrt{a}}^{\arcsin\sqrt{b}}(1-\cos2t)dt=\left[t-\frac12\sin2t\right]_{\arcsin\sqrt{a}}^{\arcsin\sqrt{b}}\\=\arcsin\sqrt{b}-\arcsin\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b(1-b)}+\sqrt{a(1-a)}.$$

Comment: Why did you delete the old answer instead of editing it? Or is this what happens after delete/undelete?